# Adding Playhaven SDK to Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play, playhaven

The Playhaven SDK does not seem to work when I add it to Android Studio. It gives me the error:

```
Error:(32, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

Here is my process to replicate the error:

1. File-> Import Module
2. Select the unzipped Playhaven SDK folder.
3. Import the module `playHavenAndroidSDK`
4. Allow Android Studio to convert it to Gradle format

Any tips to make this SDK work in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the Playhaven SDK work in Android Studio, I had to do the following, in conjunction with the above steps.

1. Open up the `build.gradle` for Playhaven
2. Change it from the Android Studio generated to the following:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 21
       buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

       defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 10
           targetSdkVersion 21
       }

       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
           }
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
       compile files('libs/gcm-client-3.jar')
       compile files('libs/json-path-0.8.1.jar')
       compile files('libs/json-smart-1.1.1.jar')
       compile files('libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
       compile files('libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar')
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
   }
   ```
3. I then had to modify the initialization statement to:

   ```
   try {
       PlayHaven.configure(this, R.string.token, R.string.secret);
   } catch (PlayHavenException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

It appears that the SDK uses certain aspects of the 19+ API, but uses a `compileSdkVersion` of 17, causing errors. The fastest solution I've found is to just change the `compileSdkVersion` and add Google Play to the `build.gradle`

4. I then added the module as a dependency to the project.
5. Lastly, ensure there is no overlap on the build.gradle file via:

   ```
   packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
       exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
   }
   ```

Comment: Holy cow, at this for fricken hours! For future readers, I was trying to use a  _newer_ version than this answer provides and it did not work. Specifically these versions were necessary.